# Como mostrar no IDE do VB6 em abas, os forms abertos do projeto

Tags: visual-studio, visual-basic-6, ide

Como mostrar no IDE do VB6 em abas, os forms abertos do projeto? Em Delphi ele já mostra todos, mas em VB6 eu não sei, nunca vi VB6, é a primeira vez. Como fechar os forms abertos? Isso em design time, não run time. Não é fechar na Aplicação, mas no Projeto(vbp), pois eu abro a janela More Window e lá tem um monte de form aberto e não consigo fechar.

Comment: Na IDE nativa não há essa possibilidade terá que usar um Add-In como por exemplo o CodeSmart desenvolvido para Axtools.

Comment: @davidterra, e como eu fecho os forms abertos? Tem um More Windows onde eu tenho listado lá todos os Forms. Como eu fecho os que eu não quero utilizar?

Comment: Não há na nativo na IDE com essa funcionalidade, vc pode instalar o add-in MzTools https://www.mztools.com/ que traz essa e outra funcionalidades.

Answer (score 2):

Basta ir em <kbd>TOOLS</kbd> -> <kbd>OPTIONS</kbd> -> <kbd>ADVANCED</kbd> e marcar a opção <kbd>SDI Development Environment</kbd>